# Why i get null insted of mock?

Tags: spring-boot, testing, mockito

I have a project with follwing classes:

```
@Repository
public interface SensorRepository extends JpaRepository<Sensor, Long> {
}
```

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SensorsServiceImpl implements SensorService {
    private final SensorRepository sensorRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Sensor save(Sensor sensor) {
        return sensorRepository.save(sensor);
    }

    ...
}
```

I created test to try Mockito

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class SensorsServiceImplTest {
    @Mock
    private SensorRepository sensorRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private SensorService sensorService;

    @Test
    public void wasSensorSaved(){
        Sensor sensor = Sensor.builder().id(1L).build();

        when(sensorRepository.save(sensor)).thenReturn(sensor);

        Sensor savedSensor = sensorService.save(sensor);

        assertThat(savedSensor).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

But when i run this test, i get excpetion, what sensorRepository is not mock, it is null.
If i get mock right in test, like

```
        SensorRepository sensorRepository1 = mock(SensorRepository.class);
        SensorService sensorService1 = new SensorsServiceImpl(sensorRepository1);
```

it works correctly. Where can be a problem?

Comment: No equals and hashCOde in your `Sensor` entity as that is what mockito uses for the matchers to determine the instance. For JPA make sure you have a proper imple,mentation and don' tuse LOmbok @Data for entities as that has a wrong equals/hashCode method for JPA.

Comment: I have equals() and hashcode(), and how is this related to creating mocks?

Comment: Read half, my mistake use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` instead of `@RunWith`. You are using JUnit5 (judging from the class visibility) and not JUnit4.

Comment: RunWith is JUnit 4, ExtendWith is JUnit 5. You have to pick the correct annotation

Answer (score -1):

I solved it adding annotation `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: That is **not** the solution as it will now run a full blown integration test which is way and way slower then a simply mockito based test.